# How to update column value of delta table based on other column of delta table

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

i have a delta table:

```
CertificationVariant_errors_detailedDescription     Flag
Software part                                        0
Software part                                        0
Software part                                        1
Software part                                        0
Software part                                        1
```

if Flag value is '0' then i need update CertificationVariant_errors_detailedDescription column value as empty string

how to achieve the same

output should be like:

```
    CertificationVariant_errors_detailedDescription     Flag
                                                         0
                                                         0
    Software part                                        1
                                                         0
    Software part                                        1
```

how to achieve the same in delta table?

Comment: which datrabricks are you using? azure or aws?

Comment: @Rakesh Govindula  im using Azure

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` in databricks SQL.

**This is my delta table:**

[image]

**Update code:**

```
%sql
UPDATE sample1 SET CertificationVariant_errors_detailedDescription='' WHERE Flag =0;
```

[image]

**Delta table after update:**

[image]